# Highcharts (Gauge) and Highstock on the same page with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, highcharts

I am using HighCharts and HighStock and I want to display a Gauge chart (which does not exist in the HighCharts library) and a Stock chart on the same page. Thus, I have to load both of the libraries and not just HighStock as others suggested.

I am using Meteor and I am loading these libraries with the maazalik:highcharts and jhuenges:highstock packages.

However, its giving me the error 16 which states that they can't be loaded together.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you try my package, `ondkloss:highstock`? Meteor 1.1.0.2 (should not require any more packages)

Comment: Hi! Amazing package, just by removing the other two and adding your package, it started to work without any code modifications! I searched this problem and by investigating the livraries I found that they both use the same HighCharts namespace, how did you solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire code base for Highcharts is included in the Stock package. To avoid collision you should therefore only include Highstock. With your requirements you also need "Highcharts-more" and "Solid-gauge" modules.

None of the packages you reference has this specific setup, and using both cause a collision. I've created a package `ondkloss:highstock` ([GitHub](https://github.com/Ondkloss/meteor-highstock)) which satisfies your requirements. If you would like to create your own, the essense is including the mentioned files, for example like this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');
    api.use('jquery');

    api.addFiles([
        // Core
        'lib/highstock.js',
        // Extra types
        'lib/highcharts-more.js',
        'lib/highcharts-solid-gauge.js',
    ], 'client');
});
```

The sources used can be found here:

- [Highstock core](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js)
- [Highcharts more module](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.src.js)
- [Solid gauge module](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.src.js)